# Jquery a cleaner way for prepend

Tags: jquery, ajax

I recently made a wall similar to Facebook.

And I just need some advice or a better way.

So when the user submitted his post, I prepend the results to a div, and I made it this way

```
$('.get_posts').prepend('<div id="'+stream.sid+'"class="row stream-posts"><div class="span1 stream-thumb"><ul class="thumbnails"><li><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt=""></a></li></ul></div><div class="span5 stream-content"><a href="#" class="author">'+stream.author+'</a><p>'+stream.text+'</p></div></div>');
```

I know its not the best, and would like to ask a more experienced developer if there is a cleaner way to prepend the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much cleaner way to do this is to create a function that generates the HTML needed for a post -

```
function createPost(postDetails){
  var html = '';
    html += '<div id="'+postDetails.sid+'"class="row stream-posts">';
    html += '  <div class="span1 stream-thumb">';
    html += '   <ul class="thumbnails">';
    html += '    <li>';
    html += '      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">';
    ...
  return html;
}
```

This way you can simply execute - `$('.get_posts').prepend(createPost(postData));` and pass all the relevant data to the function via the `postData` argument.  Much cleaner and easier to maintain.

---

Depending on how you implemented your wall updates - you might also be able to build this HTML block on your server and send it as-is.  That way your JavaScript will not have to worry about building the markup - you can just prepend the data you got back from the AJAX call.

Comment: thank you for the help for spearing time on my question (will accept yor answer have to wait 5 mins)

Answer (score 4):

one option can be creating a html document and using [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

markup.html:

```
    <div class="span1 stream-thumb">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
         <li>
           <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt=""></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="span5 stream-content">
        <a href="#" class="author"></a>
        <p></p>
     </div>
```

```
$('.get_posts').prepend('<div id="'+stream.sid+'" class="row stream-posts"></div>');
$("#" + stream.sid).load('markup.html', function(){
   $(this).find('a:last').text(stream.author);
   $(this).find('p:last').text(stream.text)
})
```

Comment: ok... an extra file to place somewhere but smart, nice, and terribly simple to maintain +1, although I'd not like to create extra ajax calls if not needed, specially if we are talking about a massive visits page... Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, would suggest using a function, my approach is much the same as the other function-based approaches, but involves creating elements, with their various attributes, rather than treating HTML as a string (both ways work, and the HTML-as-string approach is certainly more concise).

This approach, though, in my experience, allows for more easily amending the output without having to remember whether your HTML string is properly closed and escaped:

```
function prependNewPost(elem, stream) {
    var outerDiv = $('<div />', {
        'id': stream.sid,
        'class': 'row stream-posts'
    }),
        innerDiv = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'span1 stream-thumb'
        }).appendTo(outerDiv),
        ul = $('<ul />', {
            'class': 'thumnails'
        }).appendTo(innerDiv),
        li = $('<li />').appendTo(ul),
        a = $('<a />', {
            'href': '#'
        }).appendTo(li),
        image = $('<img />', {
            'src': 'http://placehold.it/60x60',
            'alt': ''
        }).appendTo(a),
        secondInnerDiv = $('<div />', {'class' : 'span5 stream-content'}).appendTo(outerDiv);
    var p = $('<p />').text(stream.text).appendTo(secondInnerDiv);
    outerDiv.prependTo(elem);
}

$('#add').click(
    function() {
        var stream = {};
        stream.sid = 'two';
        stream.author = 'Geoff';
        stream.text = 'Some text, a pseudo-Lorem ipsum, if you will...';
        prependNewPost($('#stream'),stream);
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eUYrP/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [Creating elements with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Comment: @undefined: I'm not sure it merits a particularly high vote (despite my obvious authorial bias in this case...), it's rather less concise than the previous answers from Lix and yourself, after all. And the only reason I prefer this approach is, precisely, because I find it more convenient (if less concise) to create/manipulate HTML DOM nodes, rather than HTML strings, which seem to be too-easily mangled. But thank you kindly! =)

Comment: yes, i prefer this approach, after all it's completely dynamic, good luck man :).

Answer (score 0):

How about calling an ajax-function? You could then save the entered data, maybe parse smilies/links and return the whole div with the parsed text and append it to the wall.